# Match multiple strings in multi lines and also replace multiple strings

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, regex-recursion

I want to replace all the strings with DISPLAY="TRUE" to DISPLAY="FALSE" in the first line and vice versa in the next line in a single match.

Example:
FROM:

```
 <SYN DISPLAY="TRUE" SEARCH="TRUE" CLASSIFY="TRUE">Appels</SYN>
 <SYN DISPLAY="FALSE" SEARCH="FALSE" CLASSIFY="TRUE">103.103117.1031171012</SYN>
```

TO

```
 <SYN DISPLAY="FALSE" SEARCH="TRUE" CLASSIFY="TRUE">Appels</SYN>
 <SYN DISPLAY="TRUE" SEARCH="FALSE" CLASSIFY="TRUE">103.103117.1031171012</SYN>
```

Note that all other strings in the corresponding line of `<SYN DISPLAY="TRUE" or <SYN DISPLAY="FALSE"` could be different.

The requirement is to match and replace only in the occurrence of both lines (shown above) i.e when `<SYN DISPLAY="TRUE"` is in 1st line and `<SYN DISPLAY="FALSE"` is in the second line. Single lines with the following example pattern should not be replaced.

````
<DIMENSION_NODE>
            <DVAL TYPE="EXACT">
               <DVAL_ID ID="4294960976"/>
               <SYN DISPLAY="TRUE" SEARCH="TRUE" CLASSIFY="TRUE">2</SYN>
            </DVAL>
         </DIMENSION_NODE>
    ```
````

I tried using sed, however, I couldn't make it work.

```
sed -E 's/(<SYN DISPLAY=\")TRUE(\".+\s+<SYN DISPLAY=\")FALSE(\".+<\/SYN>)/\1FALSE\2TRUE\3/' test.xml
```

Requesting experts help to make it work :)

Comment: Why manually editing those lines will not be enough for you, Jerald? All you need to do is to modify two lines of a single file? What `Note that all other strings in the corresponding line of ( ` means?

Comment: @Quasímodo  There is 2000+ such '2 line'  patterns in the file., so its difficult to manually edit .
Sorry that the "note" part incomplete (because it was not quoted), I have corrected it now.

Comment: Is it possible that the first line has `DISPLAY="FALSE"` and the second `DISPLAY="TRUE"`, and do they have to be changed?

Comment: @WalterA  No that is not in the file  when I checked. So only DISPLAY="TRUE"  in the first line needs to be changed to  DISPLAY="FALSE" and  DISPLAY="FALSE" in the 2nd line needs to be changed to  DISPLAY="TRUE", but there can be just single line with  "DISPLAY=true", this is an XML file by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `-z` the newlines will be handled as normal characters:

```
sed -zr 's/(SYN DISPLAY=)("TRUE")([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)SYN DISPLAY=("FALSE")/\1\5\3\n\4\1\2/g' inputfile
```

In your example the remembered strings are:

```
\1=SYN DISPLAY=
\2="TRUE"
\3= SEARCH="TRUE" CLASSIFY="TRUE">Appels</SYN>
\4= <
\5="FALSE"
```

Both lines are used for the match, a single line will not be changed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and explanation. This works as expected. 
One question, Is it possible to replace the group number (1 or 2, etc ) with some other string instead?

Comment: @JeraldSabuM I do not understand your question. `\1` should be used when you want to get the first remembered group, but you are not obliged to use that string. You are allowed to write `sed -zr 's/(SYN DISPLAY=)("TRUE")([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)SYN DISPLAY=("FALSE")/syn comment=lowercase display=\5\3\n\4syn comment=otherChange display=\2/g' inputfile`

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the simplest way to achieve that, if you don't want to get into complicated regex, is to use a temporary value, like so:

```sh
sed \
    -e 's/DISPLAY="TRUE"/TMP/g' \
    -e 's/DISPLAY="FALSE"/DISPLAY="TRUE"/g' \
    -e 's/TMP/DISPLAY="FALSE"/g' YOUR_FILE
```

or, as a one-liner:

```sh
sed -e 's/DISPLAY="TRUE"/TMP/g' -e 's/DISPLAY="FALSE"/DISPLAY="TRUE"/g' -e 's/TMP/DISPLAY="FALSE"/g' YOUR_FILE
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, This works but the requirement is different, Sorry that I haven't made the question more clear. The requirement is to match and replace only in the occurrence of both lines i.e when <SYN DISPLAY="TRUE" is in 1st line and <SYN DISPLAY="FALSE" is in the second line because there could be single lines. For example, the below line alone  should not be replaced:

               <SYN DISPLAY="TRUE" SEARCH="TRUE" CLASSIFY="TRUE">2</SYN>